# Question on Independence of Events

Tags: probability

I'm working on this below problem, and am having difficulty.

> Suppose that there are two types of drivers: good drivers and bad drivers. Let G be
>   the event that a certain man is a good driver, A be the event that he gets into a car accident next year, and B be the event that he gets into a car accident the following year. Let $P(G) = g$ and $P(A|G) = P(B|G) = p_1$, $P(A|G^c) = P(B|G^c) = p2$, with $p1 < p2$. Suppose that given the information of whether or not the man is a good driver, A and B are independent (for simplicity and to avoid being morbid, assume that the accidents being considered are minor and wouldn’t make the man unable to drive).
>
> (a) Explain intuitively whether or not A and B are independent.
>
> (b) Find $P(G|A^c)$.
>
> (c) Find $P(B|A^c)$.

It seemed to me that $A$ and $B$ were not independent, since if a driver gets into an accident in year $i$, he is more likely to fit into the "bad driver" category, and so will be more likely to get into an accident in year $i + 1$. The event $A$ will then increase the probability of the event $B$, in which case they wouldn't be unconditionally independent.

However, this creates quite a lot of  issues in terms of working out part (c) due to the absence of information of conditional probabilities involving $B$ and $A$, which seems to almost imply that $A$ and $B$ must be independent, which would mean that $B$ and $A^c$ are also independent. But even though I think I have worked backwards to the intended answer, I am having difficult understanding why this is the case.

I would greatly appreciate any helpful insights.

Comment: In fact it seems the problem is fine as stated, to compute $P(B\cap A^c)$ one can decompose it as $P(B\cap A^c\cap G)+P(B\cap A^c\cap G^c)$, each of which is a product of probabilities given in the question, by way of conditional independence of $A$ and $B$ given the (lack of) occurrence of $G$.

Comment: Using this reasoning, do you see why $P(B\cap A^c)=gp_1(1-p_1)+(1-g)p_2(1-p_2)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct that $A$ and $B$ are dependent. At the same time, your intuition that it is hard to work out probabilities without exploiting some form of independence is correct as well. The next best thing to independence is **conditional independence**, which is what this exercise is teaching you to use. The idea is that when we lump good and bad drivers together we have lost the independence (since good vs bad is a confounding variable) but by splitting them apart, we can restore the independence.

Using this "splitting out" philosophy, our way of calculating $P(G|A^c)$ is to expand it out as
$$
P(G|A^c)=\frac{P(G\cap A^c)}{P(G\cap A^c)+P(G^c\cap A^c)}=\frac{g(1-p_1)}{g(1-p_1)+(1-g)(1-p_2)},
$$
and we can use the same approach in a slightly more elaborate way to solve part (c) - you will need to write both the numerator and denominator as a sum over cases depending on whether the driver is good or bad, using conditional independence to compute each term in the sum as a product of the corresponding probabilities.

One final question: do you see why the answer to (a) relies on the assumption $p_1\not=p_2$?

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer. I was able to solve (b), but am still somewhat confused on (c). How does this look? First, $P(B \mid A^c) = \frac{\Pr(B \cap A^c | G) \Pr(G)}{\Pr(A^c | G) P(G) + \Pr(A^c | G^c) \Pr(G^c)}$, and by conditional independence the numerator becomes $\Pr(B | A^c) \Pr(A^c | G) \Pr(G)$.

Comment: Your application of conditional independence is not quite right, since you are effectively "throwing out" the bad drivers and only calculating the contribution from the good drivers. Thus, in addition to a term involving $G$, you should get a second term in the numerator involving $G^c$. By the way, I find it clearest to write conditional probability in terms of intersections of events to avoid confusion - for instance, you managed to end up with a $P(B|A^c)$ expression inside your term for the numerator of $P(B|A^c)$, which is a little too recursive don't you think?

Comment: If you are still stuck, take a look at my comment under @Did above, and if still stuck let me know and I can post the details of the calculation.

Comment: Thank you again, and sorry for the very foolish errors in my above comment. How is this (which I first worked out on paper): $P(B \mid A^c) = \frac{P(A^c \cap B \mid G) P(G) + P(A^c \cap B \mid G^c) P(G^c)}{P(A^c \mid G) P(G) + P(A^c \mid G^c) P(G^c)}$. Then, by conditional independence, we break up the numerator into $P(A^c \mid G) P(B \mid G)P(G) + P(A^c \mid G^c) P(B \mid G^c) P(G^c)$.

Comment: Your first equation is correct (except for what looks like a latex error on the left side, by $C$ I assume you meant to write $A^c$?) and your second expression looks great to me :)

Comment: Thank you! (And, yes, I meant to write $A$.)

Comment: My apologies, but I have just one more question: from the problem, $A$ and $B$ are conditionally independent given $G$. But does this allow us to argue that $A^c$ and $B$ are also conditionally independent given $G$? I certainly used this above, but I haven't been able to find any corroborating evidence of such a rule in my textbook or elsewhere.

Comment: Pay careful attention to the wording of the question: "Suppose that **given the information of whether or not** the man is a good driver," this means that they are conditionally independent both on the event of being a good driver, and on the event of not being a good driver. You are right that only knowing one side (e.g. conditionally independent on the event of being a good driver) does not imply the other (e.g. conditionally independent on the event of being a bad driver).

Comment: This is a good point I actually hadn't considered. Thank you. But I think I'm still unsure on whether, given that $A$ and $B$ are conditionally independent given $G$ and now $G^c$, whether, say, $A^c$ and $B$ are also conditionally independent. I'm fairly certain such a rule holds for unconditional independence. My apologies for all of the follow-ups: thank you again for all of the help.

Comment: This does in fact follow mathematically by manipulating the definition of conditional independence :) and I encourage you to work it out for yourself.

Comment: I will definitely do so -- thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

For (c), $P(B|A^c) = \frac{P(B\cap A^c)}{P(A^c)}$. We need to find $P(A^c)$ and  $P(B\cap A^c)$.

We know that $P(A|G) = \frac{P(A \cap G)}{P(G)} = p_1 \implies P(A\cap G) = gp_1$. Similarly, $P(A\cap G^c) = (1-g)p_2$. Now, $P(A) = P(A \cap G) + P(A \cap G^c) = gp_1+(1-g)p_2 \implies P(A^c) = 1 - (gp_1+(1-g)p_2)$.

$P(B\cap A^c) = P(B \cap A^c \cap G) + P(B \cap A^c \cap G^c) = P(B\cap A^c|G)P(G) + P(B\cap A^c|G^c)P(G^c) = p_1(1-p_1)g + p_2(1-p_2)(1-g)$.

Finaly, $P(B|A^c) = \frac{p_1(1-p_1)g + p_2(1-p_2)(1-g)}{1 - (gp_1+(1-g)p_2)}$

Comment: While your expression for $P(A)$ is correct, your expression for $P(A^c)$ is a little off - this is easy to see since according to your calculations, $P(A)+P(A^c)=p_2$, not 1!

Comment: Thank you, I'll fix that.