# Conditional probability doubt: Good drivers, bad drivers, accidents, Blitzstein

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am really stuck in part 3 of this problem.

user465188, Question on Independence of Events, URL (version: 2018-09-28): [Question on Independence of Events](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2934093)

Nowhere is it mentioned that P(A|G)=P(A), that is A and G are independent. What is given is that $(A \cap B)$ and G are independent events. So, how does one derive that A and G are independent?

Comment: Not following.  The given information is that $A,B$ are independent *conditioned on $G$*.  That is, if I know the driver is good, then $A,B$ are independent and if I know the driver is bad then $A,B$ are independent.  Of course, one hardly expects $A,G$ to be independent.  For instance, it may be the case that good drivers get in an accident in any given year with probability $.01$, independent of all other years, and that bad drivers get in an accident  in any given year with probability $.05$, independent of all other years.

Comment: Thank you. So you are saying that A AND B are independent conditioned on G, right?

Comment: That's what the given information specifies.

Comment: To stress, one doesn't expect $A,B$ to be independent.  After all, getting in an accident in year one is evidence (not proof) that the driver is bad, so our posterior estimate for the probability of an accident in year two would increase.

Comment: Great, thank you so much!